# WebApi / OData Relational Data Oddity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata, webapi

I've noticed that when I return a collection from an API Controller (in this case an ODataController), that I do not need to explicitly use the "Include" syntax and can still access properties using the OData "$Expand".

However, when returning one result I must be explicit with my includes.  I'm looking for an explanation as to why and perhaps information regarding the configuration of how the relational data works.

Here is the code for returning a single record (api/Projects?$Expand=Customer will not work without an Include):

```
ProjectEntity project = _Db.Projects.Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
return Ok(_AutoMapper.Map<ProjectDto>(project));
```

and here is the code for returning a single record (api/Projects?$Expand=Customer WILL work without an Include):

```
IQueryable<ProjectEntity> projects = _Db.Projects;
return Ok(_AutoMapper.ProjectTo<ProjectDto>(projects));
```

Comment: Not quite understand what you mean about the include. From your description, it seems that both query statements are not using the include syntax, can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem. Besides, I suggest you could check this article to learn the use of the `$expand`: [Using $select, $expand, and $value in ASP.NET Web API 2 OData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-select-expand-and-value)

Comment: The difference is that the first is returning `IQueryable<>`, so it can be altered by the OData processing pipeline to include (`Select`) the data needed. In the later case you are returning preloaded object w/o the related data, so nobody can return more data than what is included there.

Comment: @ZhiLv to load a relational object with EF core, you use the ".Include(i => i.RelationalObject)".  In oData you use "$Expand=RelationalObject".  But the collection is automatically mapping the objects with out my instruction to do so.